# Regex to remove first two characters of a string if they are alphabets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My client uses SKUs from which they change the first two digit suffix to represent changes/updates in models. As an analyst, I need to make a unique list of SKUs to use in my data studio dashboard. A sample of the SKUs would look like:

```
NP9151BM01
NL9151BM01
NL6004SL01
NN6004SL01
NP1927YM05
NN1927YM05
NQ1296BM01
NG1296BM01
NQ1044YL04
NN1044YL04
NP9151YM05
9151YM05
1044YL04
```

I need to use regex to check if the first two characters are alphabets and remove them if they are. For example, if I have `NP9151BM01` and `NL9151BM01` as SKUs, I need to remove `NP` and `NL` from them to end up with the exact same SKU. However, if I have `9151YM05` or `1044YL04` as SKUs, I need to keep it as it is.

For my solution, I have researched on google and stack overflow and I've found this regex `(?<=^..).*$` which will remove the first two characters in all SKUs but I'm not sure how to customise it to only remove the first two characters if they are alphabets.

I would appreciate any help that I can get with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the first two alphabets:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"^[A-Z]{2}",)
```